# how to create a shared directory for all reference library in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reference

I am developing an application that contains around 30 projects using vs 2008. what I want to do is that I want to create a shared directory where I am going to save and reference all required libraries.

the problem is that I want to create that directory outside the application folder. (in my C driver ex. 'C\MyDLL'. is that possible in VS 2008. if not is there any work around solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, why not?  The .NET reference assemblies also come from another directory, c:\program files\reference assemblies.  Use Add Reference + Browse to pick the reference from your own directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Place your .Dll files wherever you want ex: c:\mydllfolder\my.dll. The open visual studio and in your solution explorer right click the project and choose "add reference". When the Reference Manager window appears click the "Browse" button, navigate to your dll folder and select the dlls you want to reference.

Comment: can I reference that directory (c:\mydllfolder\) with my solution so that all projects can automatically use that directory and retrieve the required dll files

Comment: No. You will need to add a reference to each project in the solution. This is a one time thing though. Next time you open the solution the references will remain.